# Rounded Buttons in XAML for a window store app

Tags: c#, xaml

This seemed to me a really simple question 2 hours ago, but haven't made any progress with it.

My first search last night, said to create a rounded button, you just put it in a border, and round the edges of the border, like this,,,

```
    <Border BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            CornerRadius="10"
            Padding="4"
            Background="#FFB8B1B1"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Width="45"
                Height="35"
                Name="GetFileName"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                BorderThickness="0"
                FontSize="16"
                Foreground="Black"
                Tapped="GetFileName_Tapped"
                Background="#FFB8B1B1">Pick</Button>
    </Border>
```

This looks good, but I wanted one thing to look better.  When you hover over the button the background changes color, but not the background of the border.  To achieve this second part has stumped me.  Any leads would be appreciated.  Thanks, John.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to use ControlTemplate and VisualStateManager

```
            <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                        x:Name="MBorder"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        CornerRadius="10"
                        Padding="4">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MGrid.Background" Value="#FFB8B1B1"/>
                                    <Setter Target="MBorder.Background" Value="#FFB8B1B1"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MGrid.Background" Value="Green"/>
                                    <Setter Target="MBorder.Background" Value="Green"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MGrid.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                    <Setter Target="MBorder.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>


                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid x:Name="MGrid">
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                        Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>

    </Button>
```

Comment: This was extremely close.  It was definitely enough to mark as the answer, which I will, but it is missing some things.  I will put my alteration in the answer I post.  The missing ingredient is referencing the background of the border.  Not sure if it is protocol to edit your response, or post another answer.  I will do the later.  Many Thanks!

Comment: I edited the code and added x:Name="Border" and some addional visualstate manager setters. now the border changes the color as well

Comment: Many Thanks Mihkel!   It wasn't a major issue, but it adds a little polish to my app that makes me happy as I develop and test.

Answer (score 0):

I used @Mihkel 's Answer to solve this.  However, his answer misses the key ingredient, that being the background of the border.  I named the border in the control, as well as set a Template binding in the border.  Then referenced that, as well as the background of the button.  I am trying to put the changes in bold, but they just appear as **, the code encased in the stars is the changes.

```
 <Button Content="Pick"
        Width="45"
        Height="35"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        BorderThickness="0"
        FontSize="16"
        Foreground="Black"
        Tapped="GetFileName_Tapped"
        Background="#FFB8B1B1">

        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Green" 
                    CornerRadius="10"
                    Padding="4"
                    **Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"**


                    Name="TheBorder"
                    >

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MGrid.Background" Value="#FFB8B1B1"/>
                                    **<Setter Target="TheBorder.Background" Value="#FFB8B1B1"  />**

                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MGrid.Background" Value="Green"/>
                                    **<Setter Target="TheBorder.Background" Value="Green"  />**
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MGrid.Background" Value="Blue"/>
                                    **<Setter Target="TheBorder.Background" Value="Blue"  />**
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>


                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Grid x:Name="MGrid">
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>

    </Button>
```

Of note, this is going to be used in an open source project called Essential Video Editor.  An early version is in the windows store.  The source code is in GitHub.com/gibbloggen  And, when I publish this part, I will credit this post, in way of a reference.

Comment: I added fix and comment to my answer. It should solve the problem.